# What can we say about the homogeneous spaces $E_8/E_7$ and $E_7/E_6$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

For the three exceptional compact Lie groups $E_8, E_7, E_6$ we have the inclusions
$$
E_6 \subseteq E_7 \subseteq E_8.
$$
What can we say about the the homogeneous spaces
$$
E_8/E_7, ~~~~ E_7/E_6?
$$
Do they look anything like spheres? I am motivated by the case of the homogeneous spaces $SU_n/SU_{n-1}$, $SO(n)/SO(n-1)$, and $Sp(n)/Sp(n-1)$, that are all spheres of some dimension.

Comment: There is a paper devoted to $E_8/E_7$: "On the homogeneous space $E_8/E_7$". By. Ichiro YOKOTA, Takao Imai and Osami YASUKURA. J. Math. Kyoto Univ. (JMKYAZ)
23-3 (1983) 467-473.

Comment: @Alain: Are you talking about real groups or complex groups?

Comment: @Sasha: he says compact, so he means real and compact.

Comment: See the answer of José Figueroa-O'Farrill to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75525/matrix-groups-transitive-on-the-sphere to see that they are not spheres.

Comment: @Ben: Sorry but I do not see any mentions of $E_8$ or $E_7$ in Figueroa-O'Farrill's answer.

Comment: @AlainRochefort: sorry, I thought that Simons proved that every compact Lie group acting transitively on the sphere lies in his list. Actually, he only proves this for compact Lie groups acting transitively on the sphere and preserving a constant curvature metric.

Comment: @BenMcKay:  The answer is the same.  The list of compact groups acting transitively on the $n$-sphere was actually determined in this paper: Montgomery, Deane; Samelson, Hans *Transformation groups of spheres.*  Ann. of Math. (2) 44 (1943), 454–470.  A posteriori, it follows that all such groups act preserving a constant curvature metric.  Of course, the point is that $E_8$ and $E_7$ don't appear on this list, so, in particular, no homogeneous space of the form $E_8/K$ or $E_7/K$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.